# WebView crashing Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, expo

I have a view which is meant to render some HTML which is fetched from a API, in one screen I have a the first `<p>` element (a short description) and a "Read more" button which then navigates the user into the view with `WebView` it also passes the whole HTML as a parameter (I'm using React Navigation) into a component which wraps the whole view and passes it down as a props.

For some reason visiting this screen for the first works fine BUT after visiting this screen from another source (say another profile and clicking "View Details") , it seems to crash only the **Expo client** but it does not throw an error.

Here's the code for the view with the `<WebView>` component

```
interface Props {
  htmlString: string;
}

export const DetailsView: React.FC<Props> = ({ htmlString }) => {

  // Set starting state
  const [HTMLString, setHTMLString] = useState<string | null>(null);
  // If props and current state are diferent
  if (HTMLString !== htmlString) setHTMLString(htmlString);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          originWhitelist={["*"]}
          injectedJavaScript={`
            // JS for some basic styling
            document.body.style.lineHeight = 1.7;
            document.body.style.fontFamily = "Montserrat";
            `}
          source={{ html: HTMLString }}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

The wrapper for this component is only responsible for extracting the params passed from React Navigation

```
export const DetailsConnector: React.FC<Props> = ({ route }) => {
  return <DetailsView htmlString={route.params.htmlString}></DetailsView>;
};
```

And to navigate into this screen, all I've done is pass the HTML (saved in state) fetched from the API as a [parameter for the route](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/). I've done this through a simple Button

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate("Details", { htmlString });
  }}
>
  <Icon name="read" size="md" color="black" />
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

- By using `useFocusEffect` I confirmed the HTML string is indeed being passed down everytime the screen is in focus.
- I tested removing the `InjectedJavaScript` prop and passed some dummy HTML and the Expo App is still crashing.

Comment: hi there! this is pretty close to being a very well phrased question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! the only thing missing is that the code here is not actually runnable. here's more help on how to provide a better example so you can get help more quickly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'll change it up a bit, thanks